# Unexpected EOF while parsing when i try to run my code

Tags: python

I'm getting this error while running this code

File "", line 35
print(log.score(x_test, y_test)
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

```
def getTokens(input):
tokensBySlash = str(input.encode('utf-8')).split('/')
    allTokens = []
    for i in tokenBySlash:
        tokens = str(i).split('-')
        tokensByDot = []
        for j in range(0, len(tokens)):
            tempTokens = str(token[j]).split('.')
            tokensByDot = tokensByDot + tempTokens
        allTokens = allTokens + tokens + tokenByDot
    allTokens = list(set(allTokens))
    if 'com' in allTokens:
    allTokens.remove('com')
return allTokens

drive.mount('/content/drive')
urls ='/content/drive/My Drive/the_better_data1.txt'
readurls = pd.read_csv(urls, ',', error_bad_lines=False)
dataurls = pd.DataFrame(readurls)
dataurls = np.array(dataurls)
random.shuffle(dataurls)

y = [d[1] for d in dataurls]
corpus = [d[0] for d in dataurls]
vectorize = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=getTokens)
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_spilt(x, y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=42)
log = LogisticRegression()
log.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(log.score(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Please read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [edit] your question. I would also suggest reading [ask]

Comment: Your print statement on the last line is missing a parenthesis at the end.